# Could anyone tell me why this returns an empty list (NPE)?

Tags: java, exception, merge, linked-list

I have this code that is supposed to merge two instances of `SortedLinkedList` into one SLL (based on mergeSort merge), but is returning an empty list instead:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
    extends LinkedList<T> {

private LinkedList<T> list; // the sorted list

// constructor, sorted with insertion sort
public SortedLinkedList(LinkedList<T> in)
{
    if(in.peek() == null || in.size() == 1)
        return;
    else {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
        for(T e : in)
            list.add(e);
        int i, j;
        T temp;
        for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            j = i;
            temp = list.get(j);
            while(j > 0 && list.get(j-1).compareTo(temp) > 0){
                list.set(j, list.get(j-1));
                j--;
            }
            list.set(j, temp);
        }
}
}

// return the union of the sorted linked lists this
// and other
public SortedLinkedList<T> makeUnion( SortedLinkedList<T> other)
{
    list = new LinkedList<T>();
    SortedLinkedList<T> temp = new SortedLinkedList<T>(list);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(i < this.size() && j < other.size()){
        if(this.get(i).compareTo(other.get(j)) <= 0){
            temp.add(this.get(i));
            i++;
        }
        else {
            temp.add(other.get(j));
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i < this.size()){
            temp.add(this.get(i));
            i++;
    }
    while(j < other.size()){
            temp.add(other.get(j));
            j++;
        }
    return temp;
}

// print the items in list
public void print()
{
    for(T e : list)
        System.out.println(e);
}
}
```

In the SLL constructor, I have it simply return on a `null` list (and the private variable, list, is initialized in the first line of this method). However from what I know, this should still give me an SLL object (initially also `null`). I can add to temp just fine in the method itself, but get a `NullPointerException` when printing the list.

I realize it's not very efficient to use get with `LinkedList`. I'll switch them with an iterator after I settle this.

Any hints would be quite appreciated.

EDIT: Interestingly, I get the same result if I put both lists in a temporary LL and then use the constructor on it. The types are compatible since SLL extends LL:

```
public SortedLinkedList<T> makeUnion( SortedLinkedList<T> other)
{
    LinkedList<T> temp = new LinkedList<T>();
    temp.addAll(this);
    temp.addAll(other);
    SortedLinkedList<T> merge = new SortedLinkedList(temp);
    return merge;
}
```

EDIT2: It seems @Mead was correct... while size() and get() seem to work for the SLL, add() does not. I was thinking that since I'm extending LinkedList, it would work with the SLL as well. It didn't, and overriding them did nothing as well... I'm out of ideas for this. Suggestions?

Comment: Rather than giving us some code and describing the rest, please present a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. It's very unclear why you're assigning to the `list` instance variable within the `makeUnion` method... I would expect that to leave the existing list alone. The logic of your loops is also somewhat problematic - I expect you want the `while` loop to be *after* the `for` loop, but you need to check in the loop whether you've exhausted `other` as well...

Comment: There's a few problems with this (Eg. that is not a correct implementation of mergesort).
You need to have test code proving that add(), get(), and size() are working. Then test instantiation with a call to the SortedLinkedList constructor passing a LinkedList works (as in your code above) - and that add(), get(), size() still work after that instantiation. With the manner hinted at by your instance variable 'link', I have doubts they work correctly - it appears you're extending one of the Java List classes, but also using a private instance variable 'list'.

Comment: Heh. My psychic powers tell me the answer is probably replace `list = new LinkedList<T>();` with `LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();`  but really, presenting the whole program would help - any answer would be guess work at code we can't see.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks Jon for bringing that up, I fixed the merge for now and took care of the cases.

@Mead I didn't want to have you guys looking at a mess which is why I thought I could get away with only that snippet. The variable list is declared at the top, my apologies. The problem is that the makeUnion method is supposed to return an object of type the class constructor, so I'm sure the line where I declare temp is where I'm going wrong.. .

Comment: Just to be annoying, making a sorted list extend the List interface is conceptually wrong, since you can not respect the List contract - that is, elements are kept in the order of insertion. That's why there is no SortedList interface in java, while there is a SortedSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! Your edit pretty much reveals your problem: you're not extending the LinkedList properly. Fix that, and then work on union.

The problem at hand: This is a class called `SortedLinkedList`. We can assume it's meant to be just like LinkedList, but the values in it are sorted. So, given that, this should work:

```
LinkedList<Integer> unsorted = new LinkedList<Integer>();
unsorted.add(200);
unsorted.add(100);
unsorted.add(300);
SortedLinkedList<Integer> sorted = new SortedLinkedList<Integer>(unsorted);
System.out.println(sorted.size());
for (Integer i : sorted) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
// Should print out:
// 3
// 100
// 200
// 300
```

But it will not. Run your code, what does it print out?

Back? Why did it print out that? First, consider two variables you can use in the class's code: `this` refers to the SortedLinkedList object, and `this.list` refers to an instance variable inside that SortedLinkedList object. Then let's look at the constructor: when you add to the list, you're calling `this.list.add()`. What you have written makes SortedLinkedList a wrapper around the `list` instance variable - you're not adding to the SortedLinkedList (`this`) you are adding to a list inside that (`this.list`).
The only methods that use your `this.list` instance variable are the constructor, print, and makeUnion. All the other LinkedList methods aren't aware of the `list` variable, so when I call get():

```
LinkedList<Integer> unsorted = new LinkedList<Integer>();
unsorted.add(200);
unsorted.add(100);
unsorted.add(300);
SortedLinkedList<Integer> sorted = new SortedLinked<Integer>(unsorted);
System.out.println(sorted.get(0));
```

It doesn't know to look in your `this.list` variable, so it won't get 100 to print. In fact, it will crash because there is no value in index 0. You didn't add to the instance variables that get() actually uses, so the methods think that SortedLinkedList object is empty. `this.list` is a new variable that the inheritted methods don't know about.

So, if we examine your latest edit:

```
public SortedLinkedList<T> makeUnion( SortedLinkedList<T> other)
{
    LinkedList<T> temp = new LinkedList<T>();
    temp.addAll(this);
    temp.addAll(other);
    SortedLinkedList<T> merge = new SortedLinkedList(temp);
    return merge;
}
```

`temp.addAll(this)` doesn't work, because all the methods of `this` think that the list is empty because they're not looking at `this.list`. `temp.addAll(other)` doesn't work either, for the same reason.

What is common when you extend classes is that you want the existing methods to continue working. This means that you need to store the data where get() and other methods expect it to be. How do you do that? Well, you're already doing it! **You are already doing the right thing** - but you are doing it on the instance variable `this.list` instead of `this`. Start calling `this.add()`, `this.set()`, `this.size()` instead of `this.list.add()` and remove the instance variable `list` completely - it's not needed, you have `this`. Then the data will be where the other methods expect it to be.

(And call super() on the first line of your constructor, so the code in the super class's constructor is called). Good luck on your homework - I'd recommend testing the object works as-is before adding new methods.

Comment: Well, now I feel extraordinarily dumb. Thank you for that quite insightful comment...One question though: when I do it like that I am still obliged to have 'list' point to 'this', which gives the "leakng this in constructor warning". Since list is private, this would be safe, correct?

Now I only need to figure out how to construct the temp object for the merge method...

Comment: Sounds like you still have (and are using) `private LinkedList<T> list`. None of the inherited methods know about it, stop using it and delete the instance variable from your code. 
If you want to do the sorting in a temporary list, use a local variable, then add the sorted elements to your list (`this`).

Comment: Sorry about being so annoying, I actually figured it out shortly after posting that comment (I had it correct, but had missed an instance of this in my code... sleeplessness does that to a mind) but fell asleep yesterday. In any case, I apologize for being so thick-headed! I'm sure I'll remember this oddity for quite some time. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

just curious after looking at the implementation, but couldn't you have just done a .addAll(...) followed by a Collections.sort(...)? That's what I would have preferred personally.

Comment: Since this is homework, I am not allowed to use Collections.sort nor list.toArray -> Arrays.sort unfortunately.